# What is a "surrogate model"?

Tags: machine-learning, explainable-ai

While reading about model explainability and model accountability, the term surrogate model keeps appearing. I had an idea about what it is but it does not seem to make sense anymore:

- **What is a surrogate models?**
- **Why are surrogate models good for explainability?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "surrogate" is just a stand-in or proxy.  In data science the word "surrogate" is used in more than one way (Bayesian hyperparameter optimization comes to mind).  For interpretability, it seems to be used mostly to mean a more-interpretable model (maybe linear/logistic regression) that is trained to approximate the main, usually black-box, model (maybe boosted trees or a neural network).

See e.g. https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/global.html.  (The author refers to LIME as a "local surrogate" method and differentiates the "global surrogate" method, but I'm used to hearing just "surrogate" as a global one.)

Comment: I had exactly the same example in my mind, the GP surrogate model to approximate the cross validation score as a function of the hyperparameters, a great example to explain the surrogate model.

Comment: thanks Ben! Its a great explanation

Answer (score 2):

A surrogate model is an approximation model for a given function.

The original function is generally a black box function that we can sample from and based on the samples we can optimize our surrogate model to approximate the behaviour of the original function.

A surrogate model can be a neural network, an ensemble method, a gaussian process which can be interpreted and used later for explainability.